# ¿Cómo concatenar dos variables en un JTextField en java NetBeans?

Tags: java, mysql, netbeans

Básicamente tengo dos variables, nombre y apellido, para ahorrar espacio en la interfaz, quiero que estos dos se introduzcan en una misma caja de texto, ya lo intente de la siguiente forma y no he podido:

```
public void buscarNombreCliente() {
    ClienteC objCliente = new ClienteC();
    if (txtNitClienteFactura.getText().length() > 0) {
        try {
            CachedRowSet crs;
            crs = objCliente.buscarNombreClienteC(Integer.parseInt(txtNitClienteFactura.getText()));
            crs.getMaxRows();
            if (crs.next()) {
                txtNombreClienteFactura.setText(crs.getString(1)+" "+crs.getString(2));
            } else {
                JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(this, "Cliente no encontrado");
            }
        } catch (SQLException ex) {
            JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(this, ex);
        }
    }
}
public CachedRowSet buscarNombreClienteM(int id) throws SQLException{
    Connection con;
        con=DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/proyectojoan?" + "user=root&password=");
        PreparedStatement ps;
        ps=con.prepareStatement("{call spBuscarNombreCliente(?)}");
        ps.setInt(1, id);
        ResultSet rs=ps.executeQuery();
        CachedRowSetImpl crs=new CachedRowSetImpl();
        crs.populate(rs);
        con.close();
    return crs;
}

public CachedRowSet buscarNombreClienteC(int id) throws SQLException{
return new ClienteM().buscarNombreClienteM(id);
}
```

Aclaro de una vez que las variables las cargo con datos desde MySQL.
Agradecería mucho su ayuda.

Comment: Sería de gran ayuda que incluyas más sobre tu código, ejemplo, cómo obtienes los datos de MySQL, dónde tienes declaradas las dos variables, etc.. Sería bueno ver tu escenario completo.

Comment: ya esta ahí para que lo veas

Comment: @JOhan el problema es el CachedRow que no esta obteniendo valores, la forma de concatenar los valores es adecuado pero no lo puede realizar puesto que CachedRowSet  no tiene valores.

Answer (score 0):

Suponiendo que tu `JTextField` es txtNombre, para concatenar el contenido de dos variables tipo String se realiza precisamente mediante el operador +.

```
nombre + apellido;
```

en el caso del ejemplo que muestras agregas un espacio y lo cual es valido y correcto.

```
txtNombre.setText(nombre +" "+ apellido);
```

en el caso del código tambien es correcto:

```
 txtNombreClienteFactura.setText(crs.getString(1)+" "+crs.getString(2));
```

Aquí el problema es que el `CachedRowSet` no esta obteniendo valores, por esta razón no trata de agregarlos mediante `setText()`

```
 CachedRowSet crs;
            crs = objCliente.buscarNombreClienteC(Integer.parseInt(txtNitClienteFactura.getText()));
            crs.getMaxRows();
            if (crs.next()) {
                txtNombreClienteFactura.setText(crs.getString(1)+" "+crs.getString(2));
            }
```